# Email Notification using Events System

Tags: workflow

Looking for a solution to add email notification to workflow in Tridion 9.1. I'm not the developer so I just need directions on where to look or who to contact. I'm getting pushback from my development team. Said it can't be done. I just don't believe that!! I read the blog post at https://velmuruganarjunan.wordpress.com/2018/02/ and looking for more information.

Answer (score 1):

We've been sending emails from Tridion workflows ever since I remember... while there isn't a "native connector" for emails, there's nothing simpler to do in an event or workflow step than to call the [few lines of code](https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-send-emails-from-csharp-net-the-definitive-tutorial/) required to send an email...

What is typically harder to do is to determine who should get that email, and when, and ensuring it's not being ignored due to email frequency, etc.

Here are some pointers:

- [How can I send email notifications within a Tridion Workflow process?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4373/how-can-i-send-email-notifications-within-a-tridion-workflow-process)
- https://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2015/04/13/wf4t-workflow-framework-for-tridion/